# German Umlaut in python json body request

Tags: python, python-requests

I send a POST command to the RASA chatbot with a message in it. My requests looks like this

```
import requests
import json
jsonbody = '{"message": "Wann ist der nächste Feiertag?"}'
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook', data=jsonbody,
                              headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
js = r.text
rep = json.loads(js)
```

I get `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None` while running `rep = json.loads(js)`.

After further investigation i found out that I got a `Response 400` from the POST request.

I tried several things, for example I changed the german `ä` into `ae`. This works perfect. After I print the js string `print(js)` I got the following bot response

`'[{"recipient_id":"default","text":"Der n\\u00e4chste Feiertag ist Tag der Deutschen Einheit am Donnerstag den 03.10.2019"}]'`

after I print the list `print(rep)` I got the final message.

```
[{'recipient_id': 'default',
  'text': 'Der nächste Feiertag ist Tag der Deutschen Einheit am Donnerstag den 03.10.2019'}]
```

So the problem here are German Umlaute in my jsonbody. Although after I send a request with `ae` instead of `ä` at the end they are displayed propper. I already tried to set a charset within my request like this

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook', data=jsonbody,
                              headers={'content-type': 'application/json; charset=unicode'})
```

but after executing I got the Response 400 error again.

I am using conda 4.6.2 with Python 3.6.6. I thought Python 3 can handle such special characters like German Umlaute.

Any suggestions how to allow German Umlaute in a POST request?

Comment: Wild guess -- I wonder if it would help if you created `jsonbody` as a native Python dict, and then converted it to json using `dumps`? Try `jsonbody = json.dumps({"message": "Wann ist der nächste Feiertag?"})` and see if that improves anything.

Comment: Your jsonbody string is not json to start with.

Comment: @quamrana What is wrong with jsonbody?

Comment: @quamrana yeah, but if I try another message with no Umlaute, it works as I said. According to rasa docs this has to be like this

Comment: json strings do not contain unicode characters. json allows encoding of unicode, which is why you should let json.dumps do the conversion as @kevin has suggested. See json.org - \uhhhh

Comment: @Kevin amazing, this solved the problem. Please answer my question and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @quamrana thanks for your explanation. Now I understand the problem I had!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jsonbody = '{"message": "Wann ist der nächste Feiertag?"}'
```

I suspect that the server accepting your request does not know how to parse this string. Although I *do* think your string is valid JSON (since https://www.json.org/ says that a string may contain Unicode characters), it's possible that the server's JSON parser accepts only ASCII data. You may have better luck if you encode the ä using JSON's `\uXXXX` unicode escape sequence. You can use `json.dumps` to escape all non-ASCII characters in your data.

```
jsonbody = json.dumps({"message": "Wann ist der nächste Feiertag?"})
```

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this issue, but setting encode right before sending the data through the request solved this problem:

```
jsonbody=jsonbody.encode()
```

In my case, the encoding was utf-8, the default for this function encode().

Comment: Thanks mate! Saved me alot!